# xcode UIWebView loader code HTML

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, uiwebview

I've a question about load inside the web view:

I create a Json file to get Wordpress table and work well but inside the content table i can get only pure HTML code in one Line, so if i do a request from the web view to load the content like standard code i can't see the content, but only pure code with tags:

```
[MyWeview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyJsonClass.MyContentTeble ]]];
```

This normal code working, but not to encode HTML, i will get code like:

```
NSString *HTMLData = @"<iframe></iframe>";
[palinsesto loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:nil];
```

But my code @"" is get from MyJsonClass.MyContentTable

Thanks for help.

//---------------------------------------------------------------------//

Thx for you answer White, but still not working, if i try to use that code:

```
[MyWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyJsonClass.MyContentTeble ]]];
```

Working, but i cant see the content.

I try your code and built app good, but crash after touch UITable Cell.

Think i need a Encoder inside the App to read and compile like a NormalWebBrowser a simple HTML code, but never `<html><body></body></html>` tags T_T because i get pure code and tex from WordPress Table on Mysql DB.

Any other idea?

Comment: demand is not very clear, I do not know if you want the webview does not interpret the html code but will return the plain text or something??

Comment: Yeah sorry, i will encode HTML like: NSString *HTMLData = @"<iframe src='https://www.google.com' style=' border-width:0 ' width='100%' height='480' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>";
    [palinsesto loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:nil];

Comment: Yeah sorry, i will encode HTML like: NSString *HTMLData = @"<iframe></iframe>"; [palinsesto loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:nil];
But from remote and not inside the app

Answer (score 2):

you might try the following:

```
[web loadHTMLString: @ "<html> <body> <iframe src = 'http://www.example.com', style = 'border-width: 0' width = '100% 'height = '480' frameborder = '0 'scrolling =' no '> </ iframe> </ body> </ html> "baseURL: nil];

- (BOOL) WebView: (UIWebView *) WebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest *) request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType) {navigationType
     if ([request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString: @ "www.example.com"]. location! = NSNotFound) {
     NSLog (@"%@", [WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @ "document.body.innerText"]);
     return NO;
     }
     return YES;
}
```

This is an idea.

I hope you can help

Comment: considers that if what I understand is that you get the code itself or the text content of the iframe, this is a hypothetical way you can go

Comment: Thx for you answer, but still not working, if i try to use that code:

    [MyWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyJsonClass.MyContentTeble ]]];

Working, but i cant see the content.

I try your code and built app good, but crash after touch UITable Cell.

Think i need a Encoder inside the App to read and compile like a NormalWebBrowser a simple HTML code, but never `<html><body></body></html>` tags T_T because i get pure code and tex from WordPress Table on Mysql DB.

Any other idea?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas WhiteTiger i resolving with simple code:

     NSString *HTMLData = MyJsonClass.MyWpTable;
    [contenuto loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:nil];

Thanks a lot!